# Как выглядят сайты с кучей контента или страниц на сервере?

Tags: html, sql, cms

Вопрос к fullstack разработчикам или тем кто делает сайты под ключ. Всегда было интересно как выглядит весь контент на сайте? Допустим мы возьмём сайт хабра (https://habr.com/). Каждая статья на этом сайте представлена как **отдельный html файл**, то бишь на сервере лежит куча файлов html? Или это всё находится в массивах, контент из которых потом **динамически добавляется на страницу**? Если всё же динамически как поисковик (Google/yandex/bing etc) их находят?

Comment: Не существует никаких html-файлов, тексты лежат в базе данных и сайт генерирует html-код на лету при запросе, вытаскивая все нужные тексты из базы данных. А поисковику какая разница? Сайт выдаёт html-код — поисковик его получает и обрабатывает, вот и всё

Answer (score 1):

Я разработчик PHP MVC. Обычно сайт, и хабр тоже, состоит из шаблонов страниц html, эти шаблоны по запросу заполняются контентом, который хранится в базе данных с которой работает php движок. Т.е. весь контент от кол-ва лайков до заглавия статьи расположен в соответствующих категориях таблиц базы данных, он записывается в базу данных при вводе и выводится на страницу из БД при запросе.

Comment: Кэширование статических страниц

Comment: Хорошо. То бишь есть шаблоны html(пустые) и есть весь контент из базы данных. Допустим внутри сайта мы переходим от страницы к странице и он по запросу наполняет её контентом. Этот вопрос может не в тему но, как тогда сайт понимает что есть запрос в поисковике и ему нужно сгенерировать страницу дабы поисковик могу прочитать html файл и понять на какую позицию его поместить?